# react-navigation drawer open issue

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, drawer

I have tried this

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());

this.props.navigation.navigate("toggleDrawer");
```

and

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen");
```

but still unable to open drawer from button click which is working from swipe left to right.

[image]

[image]

and in click event I tried these options.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the snippet of the code this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen"); is triggering? Ensure it first with a console.log.

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai yes it is triggering. I have checked with alert();

Comment: How do you pass your `navigation` prop?

Comment: @AndreiOlar http://i.prntscr.com/u8Y9KHieTRWvPa2lXoAzYA.png

Comment: And is it in an asynchronous function? Maybe you can't use "this." and you would have to bind the "this." or, in the top of the file create a variable like --> let self; and in the constructor assign self = this; and use self.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen");
If you don't know what im talking about, let me know.

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai it's not async function. just simple click of <TouchableOpacity>

Comment: @Rushitrivedi Hopefully you can see that I can't see your image. :)

Comment: check then what this.props.navigation is with console.log("checkingData",this.props.navigation)

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai this.props.navigation.navigate is working because other screen navigation is working. just drawer not open

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your `navigationOptions`:

```
drawerLockMode: 'unlocked'
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be

```
this.props.navigation.openDrawer()
```